# Recommended model design for large objects

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a model structure that looked like this

```
Country
 - City
  - User
   - Items
```

In my data I have about 50 countries.
Each country have about 100.000 cities.
Each city have about 10-100 users and each user have about 1-10 items.

- I want to query cities and where country is X and return the hole city object with all child objects (user and the user items).
- I want to query cities where user is X or users items is X
- I want to query users where city is X or item is X

How would you index this data in elastic search?

First I thought that I could use parent child relationships (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/parent-child.html) which lets me perform all the queries but it won't return the child objects right? This means that I would have to perform extra queries to return the children and the children children or I could use inner hits but that would need som manual mapping to the object model...

If I use nested objects I won't be able to query child objects without returning the parent? So I could not perform a query agains users and return a list of matching users? It would return the country and its cities and all the cities users?

How would you model this data? performance of search is much more important the performance of indexing the data.

Comment: did you try any with load testing, i would gone for nested or parent child and perform load testing using jmeter or something on some load. Again how are you slicing the data based on index can help you improve performance, like routing hash for parent-child. still if you can add more info about the cluster topologies you are following i can maybe help more.

Comment: Before we go into performance tests. Is it even possible to do what I want? Parent-child relationship will force me to perform additional queries to return both parent and child? So if I have multiple levels of children I would first have to fetch the countries, then the fetched countries cities and the the fetched cities users and so on... this seems like it could lead to a performance catastrophe?

Comment: And if I use nested objects it would not be possible to query just the nested objects? Lets say I want to return a list of users? (if the user is nested object  of city which is nested object of country)